# In solfège, can you pronounce "sol" like "so"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, music

From the dictionaries, it seems like at least in American English, "sol" (as in "do, re, mi, fa, sol") is always pronounced "sole," but there's a spelling variation "so" is pronounced "so".

- Oxford (or whatever dictionary Google sources): /sōl/
- Merriam-Webster: /sōl/, *or less commonly* so /sō/
- dictionary.com: /sohl/; also, so

So it seems like if you want to say /soʊ/, you have to spell it like "so"; and if see "sol", you have to say /soʊl/.

This seems strange, though, since I've almost always heard it pronounced like "so", but "sol" is still a pretty common spelling.

For instance, in these two pretty popular songs, it's pronounced "so" (but then again, the lyrics don't write it as "sol"):

- [The Sound of Music - Do Re Mi](https://youtu.be/ps52qEFiLbg?t=55s): "sew, a needle pulling thread"
- [blackbear - do re mi ft. Gucci Mane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfzlUHOFQ5k): "do, re, mi, fa, so fuckin' done with you, girl"

So are the dictionaries correct and "sol" = /soʊl/ and "so" = /soʊ/, or is pronouncing "sol" as /soʊ/ okay?

(If this isn't broadening the question too much, I'd also like to ask whether "sole" or "so" is the more usual pronunciation.)

Comment: My dictionary gives both pronunciations.

Comment: I looked at the pronunciations in OED, and it's pretty weird: Brit. /sɒl/ and /səʊl/; U.S. /sɔl/ and /sɑl/. So it looks like it's not even always the same vowel sound.

Comment: I (in the UK) was taught 'do, re, mi, fa, so'. According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge it's supposed to be written 'sol' but pronounced 'so'.

Comment: *So'* may be viewed as a corruption of *sol* for the solfege system, and may come about because the next step on the scale is *la*, so that the /l/ sounds get jammed together into one: *sola*, and then, pried apart again, become to the ear *so la*.

Comment: Wait... so you're not asking about how to pronounce 'solfège'?

Answer (score 1):

In my chorus class, we generally drop the 'L' and pronounce it as 'so'. I honestly don't think it matters which way you say it; as long as your not going to get marked off for it.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Robusto wrote:

> *So'* may be viewed as a corruption of *sol* for the solfège system, and may come about because the next step on the scale is *la*, so that the /l/ sounds get jammed together into one: *sola*, and then, pried apart again, become to the ear *so la*.

Answer (score 0):

Sol is always pronounced "so" when singing music because under no circumstances do you want to and a note when singing on a vowel. This has nothing to do with English. It has to do with keeping the throat open.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I guess that should say "end a note". However, while singing "on the vowel" is good, all good things have to come to an end: that happens with a consonant.

Comment: Under no circumstances? Did anyone tell every lyricist ever?